# No Fields in Crystal Reports DatabaseTable Object

Tags: database, delphi, crystal-reports

I'm having a problem in a Crystal Reports application where I am getting no fields in the Fields property on a DatabaseTable Object. Fields.Count returns zero for every table. This is only happening on one of our user's computers. It's working fine for all the developers in the office. We cannot see anything that is different. I'm also wondering if I am doing something that is fundamentally wrong. The documentation says for the Fields property "One object exists in the collection for every database field
accessed by the report" but we are seeing one object for every field that exists in the database for each table, not just the ones that are accessed by the report (which BTW is really what we want). We are using CR runtime version 11.5. Any ideas would be appreciated. Here is the code we're using (Delphi):

```
    procedure TfrmPCMSCrystalReportViewer.BuildColumnList;
    { Populate slColumns with the list of column. 
      For each table in the report, add every column. }
    var
      I, J: Integer;
      Tbl: DatabaseTable;
    begin
      slColumns.Clear;
      with crReport1.Database do begin
        for I := 1 to Tables.Count do begin
          Tbl := Tables[I];
          //process each column in table
          for J := 1 to Tbl.Fields.Count do   
            //add column to list
            slColumns.Add(Tbl.Fields[J].DatabaseFieldName);  
        end; //for
      end; //with
    end;
```

Comment: I can't recall the specific syntax (not being near my work computer), but isn't there a crReport1.Database.Refresh option that re-reads the table structure into the template? Perhaps the internal structure isn't up to date in the template.  This wouldn't explain why this is failing on just one user's computer, but thought I'd suggest it.  Also, is it possible that users' computers have different versions of the CR run-time installed?  I know older versions of CR can descend into DLL-hell. That might explain the difference between developers' and users' machines.

Comment: I'm not sure what "into the template" means, but if you're referring to the crystal report file itself then I don't think this would apply. We're all using the same crystal report file. As for the CR run-time, we all installed the run-time from the same installation file too. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, by "template" I mean the CR report file itself.  Sorry for the ambiguity. Regarding the run-time, just installing from the same installation file does not guarantee that the same run-time files are used, unless you're putting them in the same folder as the .exe (which isn't, IMO, a good idea.)  See this link for the Windows search path hierarchy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.80).aspx. Seagate (yes, ages ago) used to distribute a program that would show which DLLs (including folder location) were in use. Today, you could probably use SysInternals Process Explorer.